# Combining lazy and eager loading in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

My project uses Entity Framework Core as ORM. Lazy loading is enabled by default:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
}
```

I need to write a code, which processes some big collection of objects with navigation properties. To decrease amount of database requests, I would like to download the objects with their navigation properties "eagerly".

What is right way to do this? Can I just use something like this:

```
dbContext.MyObjects.Include(myObject => myObject.NavigationProperty).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Yes. This is the case when better to try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Include` forces the EF to load the data for the given property within the query.

You might also consider to use `.ToListAsync()` overload and `await` the call. It might help the thread to not freeze while loading a huge result set from the database.

Doco with examples can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager